# Call startActivity of a activity class from a different class(overlay)

Tags: java, android, mobile

i have Target.java(it is the main activity) and Layout.java.
When user clicks a button a url opens.
The button click is handled in Layout.java.

```
    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             DebugLog.LOGD("Within onClick event of 'GO' button ");
            Target.openURL();

        }
    });
```

Target.java has a static function openURL

```
    public static void openURL() {
     Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.thecinema.in");
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
     startActivity(intent);

     }
```

I'd like to know how i can make this code work, since the error im getting now is "**Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method startActivity(Intent) from the type Activity"** . I can understand startActivity will not work within a static function, but please suggest me how i could acheive the objective ..Im a newbie to android.FYI ..Thanks guys

**-Updated code :**
Layout.java

```
    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
             DebugLog.LOGD("Within onClick event of 'GO' button ");
            Target iA = new Target();
            iA.openURL();


        }
    });
```

Target.java

```
     public void openURL() {    //removed static keyword
     DebugLog.LOGD("Within nDelete event of GO button ");

     Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.thecinema.in");
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
     startActivity(intent);

 }
```

Exception thrown:

```
    03-02 10:10:28.351: D/QCAR(6820): Within onClick event of 'GO' button 
    03-02 10:10:28.351: W/dalvikvm(6820): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207d8)
    03-02 10:10:28.361: E/AndroidRuntime(6820): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-02 10:10:28.361: E/AndroidRuntime(6820): java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-02 10:10:28.361: E/AndroidRuntime(6820):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2817)
    03-02 10:10:28.361: E/AndroidRuntime(6820):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2923)
    03-02 10:10:28.361: E/AndroidRuntime(6820):     at com.ingage.pocs.phonegap.Layout$4.onClick(Layout.java:124)
    03-02 10:10:28.361: E/AndroidRuntime(6820):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
    03-02 10:10:28.361: E/AndroidRuntime(6820):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
    03-02 10:10:28.361: E/AndroidRuntime(6820):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    03-02 10:10:28.361: E/AndroidRuntime(6820):     at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    03-02 10:10:28.361: E/AndroidRuntime(6820):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    03-02 10:10:28.361: E/AndroidRuntime(6820):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
```

Guys what went wrong in here..

Comment: remove static from openURL(), when you want to use openURL other places, create object of openURL contained class and call this method. this resolves cannot make static reference error..

Comment: Thank you thinkstep.i tried creating a object of Target in Layout and tried calling non-static function openURL(Chk updated code). The func was called but an exception was thrown.. java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i was able to come up with a solution for this question.
Under Target.java i created openURL() as:

```
     public void openURL(Context context) 
    {
     Intent intent = new Intent("com.ingage.pocs.phonegap.URL");
     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     context.startActivity(intent);
     }
```

I created a new Activity OpenURL.java and associated the intent "com.ingage.pocs.phonegap.URL" with it:

```
    package com.ingage.pocs.phonegap;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class OpenURL extends Activity{

        @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DebugLog.LOGD("Within BookTicketsActivity Activity GO button ");

    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.thecinema.in"));
    startActivity(browserIntent);

}
```

}

Layout.java:

```
    private Context applicationContext;

    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
         DebugLog.LOGD("Within onClick event of 'GO' button ");
        ImageTargets ia =new ImageTargets();
             ia.openURL(applicationContext);
        iA.openURL();


    }
});
```

The best thing is, it worked :) If you guys come up with a better or more sensible solution , pls do post here.thank you

Answer (score 2):

startActivity is not static and since you call it from Target not Layout it cannot resolve call context.

You'll need to call startActivity from Layout.java or pass reference or Target to Layout class

do it like this

Layout.java:

```
deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
         DebugLog.LOGD("Within onClick event of 'GO' button ");
         Target.openURL(Layout.this);
    }
});
```

Target.java:

```
 public static void openURL(Context context) {
     Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.thecinema.in");
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
     context.startActivity(intent);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Bartek.. Could you illustrate by showing how i call startActivity of Target class from Layout class..

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply Bartek..FYI Layout.java is a non Activity class.. so when i tried the same , i get an error in eclipse sayin i cannot pass Layout.this as an arguement :(

Comment: It can't be done otherwise, you need to call startActivity from nonstatic method of Activity class. Creating new in static openURL wont help because this class won't be initialized correctly, so you will get NullPointerException on call this function. You can do a workaround using singleton pattern but its not very elegant.

Comment: Thank you bartek, i did come up with a working solution. Please give your feedback..

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
Targets iA = new Targets();
```

Did you, perhaps, mean to write

```
Target iA = new Target();
```

That would throw a `NullPointerException` because you're asking Java to find a class named `Targets` when none exists.